# I'm getting "invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined", when trying to estimate the gas fees

Tags: web3js, gas-estimate, invalid-opcode, usdt

I'm trying to estimate gas fees of a contract that I'm about to execute. My code is as follows.

```
import Web3 from "web3";
const web3 = new Web3();

const estimateGasLimit = async (
  fromAddress: string,
  outputAddress: string,
  amount: number,
  gasPrice: number,
  gasLimit: number,
  chain = 1,
  contractAddress: string
) => {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, contractAddress, {
    from: fromAddress,
  });

  return await contract.methods.transfer(outputAddress, amount).estimateGas();
};
```

I'm testing for USDT right now, whose contract address is '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7'. It works perfectly for amount 1000000, which is 1 USDT as the decimal for USDT is 6, but fails for 10000000 that is 10 USDT. I get the following error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Returned error: invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:288:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/gaurav/Work/Revamped-Everything/wallet/node_modules/xhr2-cookies/dist/xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:506:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1220:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I am very new at ethereum and blockchain, so I would appreciate any help that I could get. Thank you.

Comment: Well, do you have 10 USDT in your account???

Comment: Oh dang, I had 9.98. Is that why I was stuck for a day?

Comment: Well, that would be the very first thing that comes to mind, in light of the fact that it works successfully with 1 USDT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An invalid opcode is typically the result of either one of the following runtime operations:

1. `assert` of an expression which evaluates to `false`
2. `array[i]` where `i >= array.length`
3. Dividing by zero
4. Calling a function which receives an enum parameter as input, and passing it a value larger than that enum's maximum value

It is custom to use `require` in order to verify user input, and `assert` in order to avoid executing potential bugs in the code.

Therefore, the `SafeMath` is typically implemented with `require` and not with `assert`.

Unfortunately, some earlier implementations of this library have used `assert` instead of `require`, and such is the one implemented in [the USDT token contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7#code).

Thus, any of the following operations could trigger an invalid opcode:

```
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        ...
        assert(c / a == b);
        ...
    }

    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        ...
        uint256 c = a / b;
        ...
    }

    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        ...
    }

    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        ...
        assert(c >= a);
        ...
    }
```

As you can see, these functions are called from function `transfer`, which you are trying to execute:

```
    function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) {
        uint fee = (_value.mul(basisPointsRate)).div(10000);
        if (fee > maximumFee) {
            fee = maximumFee;
        }
        uint sendAmount = _value.sub(fee);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(sendAmount);
        if (fee > 0) {
            balances[owner] = balances[owner].add(fee);
            Transfer(msg.sender, owner, fee);
        }
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, sendAmount);
    }
```

The most typical reason for this function to revert is when it is called with an input amount larger the amount owned by the caller, which causes `balances[msg.sender].sub(_value)` to revert.

Comment: are those 4 reasons all why we get invalid opcode or are there any other reasons too ?